# Android - Sudden crash with very long GridView (1000+ items) Nothing in logcat

Tags: android, gridview, crash, gallery, logcat

My application is a kind of Gallery displaying images from the internet.
I implemented a sort of infinite GridView: I load additional items (60) when the user reaches the end of the GridView.
And as every Gallery, when you click an item, you open a detailed view of the image in another activity.

Everything works perfectly but when the GridView becomes very big (1000 items), clicking on an item immediately close the application, without even displaying the crash popup.
And logcat displays nothing about this, so it's not even a OOM exception.

I tried to debug and the crash happens when calling `startActivity(i)`.
Here is the detailed code of this part:

```
final Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Gallery.class);
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", list);
i.putExtra("position", position);
startActivity(i);
```

`list` is the famous list containing 1000+ items.

I searched on the internet for similar issues but I really can't find some so you are my last hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.
In fact I was passing too much data via `putExtra`.

So I created a sublist with a maximum of 120 items in it and I pass this list rather than the big one. It's way enough and it works well.